# Https to http inner directory redirect using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect https://www.example.com/innerdirectory/ to http://www.example.com/innerdirectory/. I tried the following code in the .htaccess file. But its still loading with https.

I have the **.htaccess** file in http://www.example.com/innerdirectory/ and its home page.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^innerdirectory/?$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/innerdirectory/ [R=301,L]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your second rewrite rule is unconditionally redirecting http://example.com/innerdirectory back to http://example.com/innerdirectory causing a Redirect loop error. You need set a condition to the rule so that it redircts https to http only. try :

```
RewriteEngine on

#if https==on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
#Redirect "http://example/innerdir" to "https://example/innerdir"
RewriteRule ^innerdirectory/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
```